# ngfor doesnt update correctly in child component

Tags: angular

My list doesnt update correctly when i use it as a component but when i add the template directly in the parent it works fine. Any one have any suggestions?

if i leave the page and come back, it loads it properly
and when i add console.log to the subscribe in the bankaccount-list component, it updates correctly when i add a new bank account.

this is the parent html.

```
 <div class="card-block card-list">
  <search-box (update)="term = $event"></search-box>
  <bankaccounts-list (update)="setSelectedBankAccount($event)"></bankaccounts-list>
<!--template from below component entered here works, but when done like this it doesnt-->
  </div>
```

this is the component that is added in the parent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bankaccounts-list',
  moduleId: module.id,
  directives: [NgClass],
  template: `
  <div class="list-group scroll-list">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let bankAccount of bankAccounts>
      <div class="card-header">
        {{bankAccount.name}}
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        {{bankAccount.description}}<br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})
export class BankAccountListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() update = new EventEmitter();
  bankAccounts: any = [];
  constructor(public userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.userDetailsService.bankAccounts
      .subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.bankAccounts = data;
    });}
}
```

More Info:
I add new accounts using a third component which is loaded in a modal.
It calls a function on `userDetailsService`

```
private _bankAccounts: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject(<any>[]);
bankAccounts = this._bankAccounts.asObservable();
```

---

```
  newBankAccount(acnt: any) {
    let bank = this._bankAccounts.getValue();
    bank.push({
      'id': Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1),
      'name':acnt.name,
      'description':acnt.desc,
      'bankAccountName':acnt.acnt_name,
      'bankAccountBsb':acnt.bsb,
      'bankAccountNumber':acnt.num
    });
    this._bankAccounts.next(bank);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class BankAccountListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() update = new EventEmitter();
  bankAccounts: any = [];
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
     public userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.userDetailsService.bankAccounts
      .subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.bankAccounts = data;
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    });}
}
```

I added the markForCheck to the subscribe and it now works through the full componant tree rather than just on the parent as was hapening before.